# how to disable one of the input field if it does not qualify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is how to disable one of the input field if it does not qualify in the following cases: if the user select a cash-In, the input field with the attributes name of credit must be disabled, so that the user can not fill it. vice versa if the user select a cash-Out, then input field with debit attributes name should be disabled.
I tried to create those script, but it does not run properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#acc').click(function(){
    var account = $("select#acc").val();
    if (account == "db"){
        $('#credit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else if (account == "cr"){
        $('#debit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
</script>
<table>
<tr><td>Account</td><td>Debet</td><td>Credit</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="acc" name="acc" required="required"> 
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="db">Cash-In</option>
            <option value="cr">Cash-Out</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="debit" name="debit" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="credit" name="credit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.change()` event instead of `.click()` event.

```js
$('#acc').change(function(){
    var account = $("select#acc").val();
    if (account == "db"){
        $('#credit').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#debit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else if (account == "cr"){
        $('#debit').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#credit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>Account</td><td>Debet</td><td>Credit</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="acc" name="acc" required="required"> 
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="db">Cash-In</option>
            <option value="cr">Cash-Out</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="debit" name="debit" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="credit" name="credit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#acc').click(function(){
    var account = $("select#acc").val();
    if (account == "db"){
        $('#credit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         $('#debit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else if (account == "cr"){
        $('#debit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         $('#credit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event, Then switch debit and credit field disabling if the user selected either of the two.

**In your case**, and you also said, that the field must be enable if the user selected the requirement,

So you should also add a condition that **will force the user to select, or else he cannot use the field.**

Look at this [**LIVE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gy8rug9e/1/)

```
$('#acc').change(function(){

    var account = $(this).val();
    if (account == "db"){
        $('#credit').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#debit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else if (account == "cr"){
       $('#debit').prop('disabled', false);
       $('#credit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else{
       $('#debit, #credit').prop('disabled', true);
    }

});
```